# Mail Command Injection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, email, code-injection

I have found one article from OWASP security vulnerabilities list [From here](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246948/Mail%20Command%20Injection). So I am little bit confuse that does it is possible in asp.net. Please guide me.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

There is this post: [Is .NET MailMessage class injection-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301339/is-net-mailmessage-class-injection-safe) but it appears to only address the fact that the email addresses are validated correctly rather than whether headers can be injected on other fields (e.g. subject).

The other vulnerability could be a dot on a single line: [Is there any injection vulnerability in the body of an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341802/is-there-any-injection-vulnerability-in-the-body-of-an-email)

I assume `System.Net.Mail` would validate all headers and check the body as I haven't seen anything to the contrary, but I haven't yet experimented myself.

Not to spread FUD, but I also found this post without any answer: [SMTP header injection in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639217/smtp-header-injection-in-asp-net) - but without an answer this is not neccessarily a vulnerability in .NET

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to ASP.NET applications specifically, it mostly concerns mail servers (SMTP) or WebMail applications (like Gmail for instance).

So unless you have a GUI in your application that allows reading and sending e-mails, this shouldn't concern you (although it is a nice read).

Comment: Lots of web applications send mail, not only web based email apps.